# Adding bookmarks and creating printable table of contents for multiple pdfs

Tags: table-of-contents, pdf, bookmarks

I want to merge multiple (100-500) pdf files created by 1.MS Word, 2. Lyx, 3. Scanned documents, give them Bates numbers (I can do this with Adobe acrobat).

I would now like to create bookmarks and a Table of contents based on bookmarks pointing to the Bates number for printing.
I am a newbie (as you can see I still use lyx/Word etc.)

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to insert pdfs inside your tex?

Comment: I can insert multiple pdf using pdfpages. I can also give the final document page numbers (BatesNumbers printing at the footer). I want to know how to get a table of contents TOC based on bookmarks pointing to BatesNumbers to print in front of the final pdf